# How to fix "The path ... is not writable", when creating a new android studio project on network share

Tags: android-studio

If I choose a location on my local harddisk then I can create a new Android Studio project, but when I choose one on a network location then I can't click Finish because there is a warning "The path ... is not writable" (where ... is the location).
Before anyone states the obvious - yes I can actually create files in the desired location.
I've tried both a Windows share and a Linux samba share.
Is there a fundamental reason that I cannot store on a network location? If not, how can I resolve it so thtat I can?

Comment: Same issue here. I can add/edit/remove files from Windows Explorer, but Android Studio doesn't seem to be using my user's credentials.